# Substituting stevia for erythritol in recipes

Tags: sweeteners

I use stevia as a sweetener now. I have seen a couple of sweets recipes that use erythritol. I have stomach issues with any sweetener that ends in "tol."

I am wondering if I can substitute stevia as the sweetener in these recipes?

Comment: Welcome to the site! What recipes and foods do you want to make? Not all artificial sweeteners are appropriate for every application, so the answer depends on the application.

Comment: I just received a cookbook for making Keto sweets. Almost every recipe uses erythritol and/or monk fruit. They are used in making ice cream, cakes, candy, brownies, frosting, cookies, pies,cheesecake, popsicles and panacotta and creme brulee. It is even suggested that the top of the CB be melted erythritol.

Comment: Are you referring to pure stevia extract powder (incredibly sweet -- hundreds of times sweeter than sugar), or a bulked blend of stevia w/ maltodextrin (Stevia in the Raw)?

Comment: I use Stevia In The Raw w/dextrose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. If you're talking about pure stevia it needs to be mixed with another sweetener to add bulk and texture, as well as to minimise its bitter after-taste. For a cake, I use erythritol + 1 tsp pure stevia at most, depending on other ingredients in the mix. You could try an allulose blend instead of erythritol, but it isn't available in the UK.